# dask cudf has no access to map_partitions

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe, cudf

I tried to create a dask_cudf dataframe but got an error.

```
import dask_cudf
import cudf


# Example pandas DataFrame with a datetime string column
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_str': ['2024-03-19 12:00:00', '2024-03-19 10:00:00', '2024-03-19 11:00:00']})

# Convert the pandas DataFrame to a cuDF DataFrame
cdf = cudf.from_pandas(pdf)

# Convert the cuDF DataFrame to a Dask cuDF DataFrame
ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(cdf, npartitions=2) # error
```

I got an error:

```
AttributeError: DataFrame object has no attribute map_partitions
```

I found that

```
cudf.core.dataframe.DataFrame # no map_partitions
dask_cudf.DataFrame.map_partitions 
dask_cudf.core.map_partitions
dask_cudf.core.DataFrame.map_partitions
dask.dataframe.map_partitions
```

How to make "dask_cudf.from_cudf" access map_partitions ? thanks

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this error. It returns `<dask_cudf.DataFrame | 2 tasks | 2 npartitions>` and works as expected with RAPIDS 24.04 nightly builds. Can you share the versions of `dask`, `cudf`, and `dask-cudf` that you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/dask-cudf/stable/api/#creating-and-storing-dataframes):

> `dask_cudf.from_cudf` is a thin wrapper around `dask.dataframe.from_pandas()`

And the first parameter `data` expected to be `pandas.DataFrame` or `pandas.Series`.

So the first option is:

```py
# Sample data frame
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime_str': [
        '2024-03-19 12:00:00', 
        '2024-03-19 10:00:00', 
        '2024-03-19 11:00:00']})

# Create Dask-cuDF DataFrame
ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(pdf, npartitions=2)
```

The second option is:

> For on-disk data that are not supported directly in Dask-cuDF, we recommend using Dask’s data reading facilities, followed by calling `from_dask_dataframe()` to obtain a Dask-cuDF object.